# Android Jetpack Compose get Activity View Model from Fragment inside Composable

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-viewmodel

I'm having an issue getting the activity view model from a fragment in a composable

```
private val birthdayViewModel: BirthdayViewModel by activityViewModels()
```

When I use viewModels() there is no issue

```
private val birthdayViewModel: BirthdayViewModel by viewModels()
```

Fetching the view model in composable like

```
val birthdayViewModel: BirthdayViewModel = viewModel()
val formItem by birthdayViewModel.birthdayFormItem.observeAsState()
```

The issue is that the form item errors to null when using activityViewModels but not when using viewModels

When I run in debug mode to check the value of the formItem I get this error message:
"Cannot find local variable 'formItem' with type com.form.FormSpec$FormItem"

Could this be a gradle versioning issue?

Please help :)

Comment: are you using `Dagger Hilt` in your project? There is a way to provide the `ViewModel` in composable using `Dagger Hilt`?

Comment: Not currently using Hilt but I will give it a try

Comment: do you have the dependency for using `activityViewModels` inside fragment? are you able to use `activityViewModels` without any `compile time` warnings/error?

Comment: Yes no issues I'm able to run the code and put the error I'm receiving when using activityViewModels in the fragment above in my question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
private val activityViewModel: ActivityViewModel by activityViewModels()
private val fragmentViewModel: FragmentViewModel by viewModels()

Composable(fragmentViewModel, activityViewModel)
```

The problem had to do with scopes.  I was not passing the view models into my composable directly, but rather, was doing this in the composable constructor which didn't lead to both of my viewModels having a fragment scope.

```
Composable(
   fragmentViewModel: FragmentViewModel = viewModel(), 
   activityViewModel: ActivityViewModel = viewModel()
)
```