# Activity view model in Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In fragment, we have

```
private val activityViewModel: MainActivityViewModel by activityViewModels()
private val fragmentViewModel: MainFragmentViewModel by viewModels()
```

to get an instance of a shared view model throughout the app (activity view model) and a view specific view model (fragment view model).

I am migrating to compose.

How to get two view models with different scopes in jetpack compose?

From the [docs](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#viewmodel), I can see this line,

> viewModel() returns an existing ViewModel or creates a new one in the given scope.

But, how do I specify the scope of the view model?

P.S.
I have already gone through [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68448250/android-jetpack-compose-get-activity-view-model-from-fragment-inside-composable) which is similar but it doesn't have any answers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Normally within a single composite tree, such as within the `setContent` content, there is one view model scope that is shared between all child composites.

You can override it if you want, using `LocalViewModelStoreOwner`:

```
CompositionLocalProvider(
    LocalViewModelStoreOwner provides viewModelStoreOwner
) {
    NextComposable()
}
```

Compose Navigation overrides it for each navigation destination. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68857871/3585796) to see how you can share it between navigation destinations.

Comment: I can create an instance of a viewModel in Activity's `onCreate` and pass it to each route. What's the difference?

Comment: @JimOvejera `viewModel()` will create/cache a view model for you, passing it down from an activity is an option, but it requires a lot of boilerplate code

Answer (score 5):

To elaborate on @Pylyp Dukhov. Since its possible to change the default provider directly in the tree, its possible to make a function that fetch a `viewModel` in a specific `ViewModelStore`.

I've made a [gist](https://gist.github.com/L-Briand/e35b2d80144c4ec613474c5288b3eb62) for that.

Here's the content :

```kotlin
/** Try to fetch a viewModel in [store] */
@Composable
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel, S : ViewModelStoreOwner> viewModelInStore(store: S): Result<T> =
    runCatching {
        var result: Result<T>? = null
        CompositionLocalProvider(LocalViewModelStoreOwner provides store) {
            result = runCatching { viewModel(T::class.java) }
        }
        result!!.getOrThrow()
    }

/** Try to fetch a viewModel with current context (i.e. activity)  */
@Composable
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> safeActivityViewModel(): Result<T> = runCatching {
    val activity = LocalContext.current as? ViewModelStoreOwner
        ?: throw IllegalStateException("Current context is not a viewModelStoreOwner.")
    return viewModelInStore(activity)
}

/** Force fetch a viewModel inside context's viewModelStore */
@Composable
inline fun <reified T : ViewModel> activityViewModel(): T = safeActivityViewModel<T>().getOrThrow()
```

Getting a viewModel on activity store is as easy as getting a viewModel from the default tree's store.

```kotlin
@Composable
fun MyComposeElement(
    fragmentViewModel: ComposeViewModel = viewModel(),
    activityViewModel: ComposeViewModel = activityViewModel()
) {
    assert(fragmentViewModel != activityViewModel)
    assert(fragmentViewModel == viewModel<ComposeViewModel>())
    assert(activityViewModel == activityViewModel<ComposeViewModel>())
}
```

Comment: It's not work in Dialog, throw Exception "Current context is not a viewModelStoreOwner."

Answer (score 0):

```
class MainViewModel: ViewModel() { }

@Composable
fun MainScreen() {
    // ViewModel with a scope of the current class.
    val screenViewModel = viewModel<MainViewModel>()
    
    // ViewModel with a scope of the activity.
    val activity = LocalContext.current.getActivity()
    activity?.let {
        val activityViewModel = viewModel<MainViewModel>(viewModelStoreOwner = activity)
    }
}
```

Please make sure to import compose viewModel.

```
import androidx.lifecycle.viewmodel.compose.viewModel
```

In addition, getActivity() function is not directly available, please use the following Context extension.
Reference: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67927037/6512100

```
fun Context.getActivity(): AppCompatActivity? {
    var context = this

    while (context is ContextWrapper) {
        if (context is AppCompatActivity) return context

        context = context.baseContext
    }

    return null
}
```

Answer (score -1):

According to this [link](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/compose/libraries#hilt-navigation)

For example if i have a `settings` navigation graph which i can navigate to `theme` and if i want to `theme` to use `settingsViewModel` that scope to this navigation graph i can achieve this by:

```
private fun NavGraphBuilder.theme(
    navController: NavController,
) {
    composable(route = MainSubScreen.Theme.route) {
        val settingsViewModel = hiltViewModel<SettingsViewModel>(
            navController.getBackStackEntry(MainSubScreen.Settings.route)
        )
        Theme(
            settingsViewModel = settingsViewModel,
            backToSettings = { navController.popBackStack() },
        )
    }
}
```

or if you want `theme` to use `settingsViewModel` that scope to `theme` itself. U can do like below or create an `settingsViewModel` instance directly inside your `theme` composable function without passing parameters around like this. If you do this you will notice that `onCleared` inside `settingsViewModel` will be called when you pressed back from `theme` to `settings`.

```
private fun NavGraphBuilder.theme(
    navController: NavController,
) {
    composable(route = MainSubScreen.Theme.route) {
        val settingsViewModel = hiltViewModel<SettingsViewModel>()
        Theme(
            settingsViewModel = settingsViewModel,
            backToSettings = { navController.popBackStack() },
        )
    }
}
```